# SSIS Convert m/dd/yyyy to yyyymmdd with inconsistencies

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl

I'm loading many files into a SQL SERVER database. I have one flat file that has a Date Column coming in as `string[DT_STR]`.
I have TWO "date fields" in my database. One is `varchar`, one is `datetime`.

Converting the `datetime` column is no issue, I just use Data Conversion/Derived Column if necessary. However, this `varchar` column is giving me trouble. Our database values for this column should be in yyyymmdd format. However, on this single file the format of the dates change.

Normally I'd do a `SUBSTRING(...)` expression here, but the difficulty is that the format of these dates change. some examples of values could be

```
08/16/2017
8/16/2017
08/6/2017
08/06/2017
10/6/2017
10/06/2017
```

This makes the challenge harder. I tried `LEN([DATE]) == NUM_HERE ? do_THING : OTHER_CALC`, but this approach failed because the length of `10/6/2017` is the same as `8/06/2017` which will give me the wrong result. Does anyone have a good workaround for this?

Comment: You should be able to just cast all of those examples directly to datetime using `SELECT CAST('08/16/2017' AS datetime)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a simple convert to date and then into the final format.  If 2012+, use `try_convert()` to trap any bogus dates.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('08/16/2017')
,('8/16/2017')
,('08/6/2017')
,('08/06/2017')
,('10/6/2017')
,('10/06/2017')

Select * 
     ,Formatted = convert(varchar(8),convert(Date,SomeCol),112)
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol     Formatted
08/16/2017  20170816
8/16/2017   20170816
08/6/2017   20170806
08/06/2017  20170806
10/6/2017   20171006
10/06/2017  20171006
```

Comment: ahhhh.. I didn't think like this! Great idea. Would i perform this in or outside of SSIS?

Comment: @MattR Either/Or... If it were me, I would do it in SSIS as a derived column.

Comment: I'm an SSIS noobie, how would I translate this into an expression? If you don't feel like "doing my homework" that is understandable, though...

Comment: @MattR Little hard without seeing you data.  One thing I often do is load my data into a staging table,  The data type of that "date" field would be varchar.  Once the data is loaded into staging, I then run any required validation/formatting/transformation routines.   This way, if the source data is bogus or unexpected, my core data is not polluted.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that

Comment: @MattR Good luck.  There is no shame in taking it step-by-step.  This is especially true with larger databases with complex business rules.  I think it is important to be able to defend your data.... from source all the way through the final presentation.

Comment: I agree. I'm a Python guy - I'd normally just write some function to do all of this loading, but the current requirement is to use SSIS only - *whole* different animal. I appreciate your wisdom here!

Comment: @MattR "Wisdom"... my wife would disagree   Thanks for the grin :)

Comment: I need your grinning power once more - Had a thought, What if i ran an Execute SQL Task after everything was loaded? `UPDATE tmp_Jadenu_Status
SET [DATE_HERE] = convert(varchar, convert(Date,[DATE_HERE]),112)
where 'FILTER_TO_WHAT_I_JUST_LOADED'`. Is that bad practice?

Comment: @MattR That works.  Just one concern... You are destroying original data, and you may be losing your audit trail, BUT if you keep the original source file (to reload if necessary), then you will be covered.

Answer (score 2):

[Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) the varchar data to datetime and convert that to a formatted string

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,(CONVERT(datetime, '8/6/2017')),112)
```